# Combining multiple nouns with a lack of attributive verbs

Tags: grammar, nouns

While listening to [a song](https://www.lyrical-nonsense.com/lyrics/hachiya-nanashi-feat-hatsune-miku/yoyoi-no-yoi/) (I believe it would be considered *denpa* or something close to it) I came across these lyrics (hesitant English translations by me):

> どうだい くたばる前に あばよ昇天
> How’s that? Before I drop dead I bid farewell my ascension to Heaven
>
> 全体死んでる目で見つめ合って
> Gazing at each other with completely lifeless eyes
>
> **行進頓服中毒敵わないね**
> *I won't win against this parade of use-as-needed poison*
>
> 振り切れた生命 本能は低迷
> I shook off my life; my instincts grow sluggish

I don't understand how to handle this "行進頓服中毒". I'm assuming that some のs are being omitted here as is the case with more casual/archaic language, but the terms and tone of the lyrics in this song are so odd (ex. "錠剤病んでるせいで投与、御礼。/ Since I was sick of those pills, my humble thanks to you for administering [them]") I wanted to check.

Comment: Frankly, being Japanese, these lyrics make no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

`中毒{ちゅうどく}` originally means "poisoning", but nowadays is used more in the sense of ["addiction"](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E4%B8%AD%E6%AF%92/#je-48528). So I would interpret `行進頓服中毒敵わない` as "[one] can't win against addiction to marching".

I suspect `頓服{とんぷく}` was just inserted for rhythm/alliteration and does not necessarily carry a meaning on its own. However, other lines also talk about taking medicine so maybe it's related after all...

In all, I think the best "translation" of this would be to just write similar nonsense in English using the overall impression of the song.